# Checking tkinter GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, button, tkinter

I have a problem with my code - it's working quite fine except the fact that the buttons that are created dont work separately, each button is dependent on others. Can You help me with making those buttons independent? I hope I've described everything well, english isn't my native language :d Here's the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import wiringpi2 as wiringpi

pin_base = 65
i2c_addr = 0x20
pin_base_2 = 81
i2c_addr_2 = 0x21
pin_base_3 = 97
i2c_addr_3 = 0x22
pin_base_4 = 113
i2c_addr_4 = 0x23
pin_base_5 = 129
i2c_addr_5 = 0x24
pin_base_6 = 145
i2c_addr_6 = 0x25
pin_base_7 = 161
i2c_addr_7 = 0x26
pin_base_8 = 177
i2c_addr_8 = 0x27

wiringpi.wiringPiSetup()
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(65,0x20)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(81,0x21)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(97,0x22)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(113,0x23)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(129,0x24)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(145,0x25)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(161,0x26)
wiringpi.mcp23017Setup(177,0x27)

NUM_MY_WIDGETS = 6
wiring_mode = [65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]

class MyWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column, label_text):
        self.button = tk.Button(text='WL', width=12, bg='red',
                                command=self.__call__)
        self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)

        self.label = tk.Label(text=label_text, width=6, bg='red')
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column+1)

    def __call__(self):
        if self.button['text'] == 'WL':
            self.button['text'] = 'WYL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'green'
            wiringpi.pinMode(wiring_mode[i],0)
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(wiring_mode[i],0)
        else:
            self.button['text'] = 'WL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'red'
            wiringpi.pinMode(wiring_mode[i],1)
            wiringpi.digitalWrite(wiring_mode[i],0)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI - TEST')

widgets = []
for i in range(NUM_MY_WIDGETS):
    widgets.append(MyWidget(i, 1, i+1))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have wiringpi2, so I commented out all the code that depends on it.  When I run the resulting script, I get 6 buttons, and if I click on any one of them, the text and color of that button changes, but the others remain the same.  I assume that's what's supposed to happen.  So I', guessing that the problem relates to the lines:

```
wiringpi.pinMode(wiring_mode[i],0)
wiringpi.digitalWrite(wiring_mode[i],0)
```

Here i is a golbal variable, and all buttons will use the same value of it.  You need to save the number in the widget.  In your **init** method, you could just add

```
self.i = row
```

and then just set

```
i = self.i
```

at the start of the call() method.

Here's a minimal example

```
import Tkinter as tk

NUM_MY_WIDGETS = 6

class MyWidget(object):
    def __init__(self, row, column, label_text):
        self.button = tk.Button(text='WL', width=12, bg='red',
                                command=self.__call__)
        self.button.grid(row=row, column=column)

        self.label = tk.Label(text=label_text, width=6, bg='red')
        self.label.grid(row=row, column=column+1)
        self.i = row

    def __call__(self):
        if self.button['text'] == 'WL':
            self.button['text'] = 'WYL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'green'
            print(self.i)
        else:
            self.button['text'] = 'WL'
            self.label['bg'] = 'red'
            print(i)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('GUI - TEST')

widgets = []
for i in range(NUM_MY_WIDGETS):
    widgets.append(MyWidget(i, 1, i+1))

root.mainloop()
```

When the color changes to green the button number is printed, but when the color changes to red, "5" is always printed.

When call is defined, python doesn't save the current value of i.  It saves a reference to the variable i.  When call is later run, the value that is used is whatever value i happens to have at the time of call, not the value it had at the time of definition.